# What's the correct replacement for flet on new emacsen?

Tags: cl-lib

I have [some code](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el/blob/a3a6e0f5856e225876e6944f8206218111bf8714/ag.el#L110) that uses `flet` to temporarily change the behaviour of functions.

```
;; prevent changing the window
(flet ((pop-to-buffer (buffer &rest args)
                      (switch-to-buffer buffer)))
   (compilation-next-error-function n reset))
```

However, Emacs' byte compiler gives a warning:

```
In ag/next-error-function:
ag.el:103:7:Warning: `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either
    `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'.
```

However, `cl-flet` works differently and doesn't suit some use cases, and I believe this is one of those cases.

The options I can see are:

1. Tell Emacs to ignore the warning somehow.
2. Roll my own `flet`.
3. Use [noflet](http://nic.ferrier.me.uk/blog/2013_06/noflet-for-object-style-functions) or [dflet](https://github.com/sigma/el-x/blob/master/lisp/dflet.el).

What is the best approach?

Comment: _"However, cl-flet works differently"_. There's a second suggestion in that warning message. ;-)

Comment: I took the old one and just renamed it (e.g., `my-flet`) and removed the obsolete warning, and use that in in any package that previously required flet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the same behavior you're used to with `flet`, use `cl-letf` to change a symbols function value.

```
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'pop-to-buffer)
           (lambda (buffer &rest _) (switch-to-buffer buffer))))
  (compilation-next-error-function n reset))
```

If you were to roll your own `flet`, the easy way would be macro that expands to a `cl-letf` form.

*Edit: rolled it*

```
(defmacro myflet (bindings &rest body)
  "Works like the old `flet'. Does not validate form structure."
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(cl-letf ,(mapcar (lambda (binding)
                       `((symbol-function ',(car binding))
                         (lambda ,(cadr binding) ,@(cddr binding))))
                     bindings)
     ,@body))

(myflet ((+ (&rest args) (apply '- args)))
  (+ 10 3 2)) ;; => 5
```

Comment: However, keep in mind the caveat from Yann Hodique's comment to Malabarba's article: "note that Emacs **24.3.1** has a subtle bug that makes `cl-letf` not a proper alternative (IIRC, it does not work for `flet`-ing symbols that are not already `fboundp`). Which is why a backward-compatible version of `flet` is a bit... [convoluted](https://github.com/sigma/el-x/blob/master/lisp/dflet.el)."

Answer (score 14):

Artur Malabarba wrote this up recently, in [Understanding letf and how it replaces flet](http://endlessparentheses.com/understanding-letf-and-how-it-replaces-flet.html).

`letf` is an alias for `cl-letf`, and while it's most likely what you want, there's a minor caveat which Artur points out:

> Unfortunately, cl-flet is not identical to the original flet—it's lexical, not dynamic.

(Nic's `noflet` package provides extended functionality along these lines.)