# How to programmatically answer "yes" to those commands that prompt for a decision from the user?

Tags: arguments

I made a custom function that combines two functions of [twittering-mode](http://twmode.sourceforge.net/) , `twittering-favorite` and `twittering-native-retweet`, however these two needs input from me by answering an yes or no question.

I want to know if there is a way to wrap those those two functions with something that will make them receive an answer without my direct intervention.

Comment: I don't use `twittering-mode` (and I won't bother to access the code), but as a general word of advice: Typically, instead of doing what you suggest (make code that simulates a user answering `yes`) it is better to make code that directly uses the code that expects the answer. IOW, try leveraging the source code path that a `yes` answer would cause to be invoked. (Just a suggestion.)

Comment: The title is misleading as this cannot be done properly in a generic way.

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14669/sort-of-autoreply-for-specific-messages-in-minibuffer/14676#14676

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT:
As @hatschipuh pointed out in the comments, an `flet`-type construction is more straightforward and doesn't rely on my idiosyncratic advice macro.  At least on my Emacs (24.5.1), `cl-flet` uses lexical scoping, so you'll need the `noflet` package for the following snippet to work.  Scroll down for the original, idiosyncratic answer.

```el
(defun my/bypass-confirmation (function &rest args)
  "Call FUNCTION with ARGS, bypassing all `y-or-n-p' prompts."
  (require 'noflet)
  (noflet
      ((y-or-n-p (prompt) t))
    (apply function args)))

(defun my/bypass-confirmation-all (function &rest args)
  "Call FUNCTION with ARGS, bypassing all prompts.
This includes both `y-or-n-p' and `yes-or-no-p'."
  (require 'noflet)
  (noflet
      ((y-or-n-p    (prompt) t)
       (yes-or-no-p (prompt) t))
    (apply function args)))
```

---

EDIT: This is the original answer, except that I fixed `my/bypass-confirmation-all` to work as advertised and changed the calling conventions a bit.

Here's a general wrapper that should work for any function.

```el
(defun my/bypass-confirmation (function &rest args)
  "Call FUNCTION with ARGS, bypassing all `y-or-n-p' prompts."
  (my/with-advice
      ((#'y-or-n-p :override (lambda (prompt) t)))
    (apply function args)))

(defun my/bypass-confirmation-all (function &rest args)
  "Call FUNCTION with ARGS, bypassing all prompts.
This includes both `y-or-n-p' and `yes-or-no-p'."
  (my/with-advice
      ((#'y-or-n-p    :override (lambda (prompt) t))
       (#'yes-or-no-p :override (lambda (prompt) t)))
    (apply function args)))
```

This code depends on this macro, which seems to be my go-to solution for everything on Stackexchange.

```el
(defmacro my/with-advice (adlist &rest body)
  "Execute BODY with temporary advice in ADLIST.

Each element of ADLIST should be a list of the form
  (SYMBOL WHERE FUNCTION [PROPS])
suitable for passing to `advice-add'.  The BODY is wrapped in an
`unwind-protect' form, so the advice will be removed even in the
event of an error or nonlocal exit."
  (declare (debug ((&rest (&rest form)) body))
           (indent 1))
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                 (cons 'advice-add adform))
               adlist)
     (unwind-protect (progn ,@body)
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (adform)
                   `(advice-remove ,(car adform) ,(nth 2 adform)))
                 adlist))))
```

Whether this code is the smartest way to handle this situation, I don't know.  In general, I like using this sort of temporary advice to make modifications of existing functions instead of duplicating the original functions' code, in part because it helps to future-proof your modified function against unrelated changes in the original.  But in this case you may need to take additional care, because if `twittering-mode` updates and changes the prompts or adds an additional one, you won't see the changes.  Since a y-or-n prompt indicates a controversial choice, that could have unfortunate consequences.

---

EDIT: It occurred to me that an example of use might be helpful.  This example works with either implementation.

```el
(defun my/twittering-function ()
  ;; This will bypass `y-or-n-p' in both commands.
  (my/bypass-confirmation #'twittering-favorite arg)
  (my/bypass-confirmation #'twittering-native-retweet)
  ;; This will bypass both `y-or-n-p' and `yes-or-no-p' in this command.
  (my/bypass-confirmation-all #'twittering-favorite arg)
  ;; Prompts in this call are not bypassed.
  (twittering-native-retweet)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this modify the behavior of the functions I would like to have behaving differently (only) inside my custom function?

Comment: Yes, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Well, not exactly, changing the behavior of both commands everywhere is something I don't feel comfortable with :(

Comment: I think I may have misread your earlier comment, then.  The only prompts bypassed are those inside the wrapped function call.  To help clarify, I added a usage example to the answer.

Comment: The following  achieves basically the same and is a good alternative I think:
`(flet ((yes-or-no-p (prompt) t)
       (y-or-n-p (prompt) t))
  body...)`

Comment: @hatschipuh In principle, yes, but at least on my instance `cl-flet` appears to use lexical scope, and this needs dynamic scope.  Updating the answer to incorporate this now.

Comment: Ah yes, the `cl-lib` uses lexical scope, the old `cl` library uses dynamic scope for flet. I did not knew about the noflet package.

Comment: See also this for alternatives to get the old behaviour of flet: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3452/9198

Comment: The `noflet` package has seen been superseded by `letf` which is in Emacs core (note, `flet` and `letf` are totally different for what I assume seemed like a good reason at the time).