# Symbol's value as variable is void: ‘yes-or-no-p

Tags: debugging, quote, characters

I have the following lines in my config file:

```
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
(setq confirm-kill-emacs ‘yes-or-no-p)
```

The latter line is what's throwing the error.  I would like to be able to use `'y-or-n-p` for some commands, like `confirm-kill-emacs`.

Comment: Always look closely at the error message. It's referring to a variable named `‘yes-or-no-p`. Note the quotation mark, `‘`, that is part of the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your cursor over the character `‘` on the line `(setq confirm-kill-emacs ‘yes-or-no-p)` and press `C-x =`.

```
Char: ‘ (8216, #o20030, #x2018, file ...) point=698 of 698 (100%) column=0
```

That's the left quotation mark (with `C-u C-x =` you can see its Unicode name: LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK). This character has no special meaning to Emacs.

You need to use the ASCII apostrophe/single-quote character instead:

```
(setq confirm-kill-emacs 'yes-or-no-p)
```

(Leaving aside why you'd use `yes-or-no-p` here since you've aliased it to `y-or-n-p`.)

Comment: I knew it was something stupid.  On your aside, could you elaborate as to how would I go about setting some commands to require "yes" while having the default just requiring "y"?

Comment: @skepticscript I don't think there's a universal recipe. Some commands have an ad hoc option (e.g. `confirm-kill-emacs`). Others hard-code the call to `yes-or-n-p` or to `y-or-n-p`. For hard-coded cases, see e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19077 and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/22569 .

Answer (score 0):

As @Gilles mentioned, once you have `fset` (aka aliased) the call to `y-or-n-p`, `yes-or-no-p` has been effectively overwritten.  Based on [the link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/22569) in his comment, it seems the best way to do things is to specifically set `y-or-n-p` on certain prompts, and that it likely isn't possible to have `y-or-n-p` as a default and override certain prompts with `yes-or-no-p`, at least not without writing a really convoluted implementation.