# How to override a function in a function only in that function?

Tags: advice

I used `(advice-add 'yas-new-snippet :override 'my/yas-new-snippet )` but I was wondering if there was something like this which would allow me to override a function in a function only in that function:

```lisp
(override-func 'yas-new-snippet 'switch-to-buffer 'switch-to-buffer-other-window)
```

What I did was override the function to open the snippet in another window. This works but assume that the package maintainer is actively maintaining. I would have to copy this when/if it gets updated. Fortunately for me yas does not get updates frequently. Another thing is that it adds more code to my config.

```lisp
(defun my/yas-new-snippet (&optional no-template)
  "Pops a new buffer for writing a snippet.

Expands a snippet-writing snippet, unless the optional prefix arg
NO-TEMPLATE is non-nil."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((guessed-directories (yas--guess-snippet-directories))
        (yas-selected-text (or yas-selected-text
                               (and (region-active-p)
                                    (buffer-substring-no-properties
                                     (region-beginning) (region-end))))))

    ;;(switch-to-buffer yas-new-snippet-buffer-name)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window yas-new-snippet-buffer-name)
    (erase-buffer)
    (kill-all-local-variables)
    (snippet-mode)
    (yas-minor-mode 1)
    (set (make-local-variable 'yas--guessed-modes)
         (mapcar (lambda (d) (yas--table-mode (car d)))
                 guessed-directories))
    (set (make-local-variable 'default-directory)
         (car (cdr (car guessed-directories))))
    (if (and (not no-template) yas-new-snippet-default)
        (yas-expand-snippet yas-new-snippet-default))))

;; Open new snippet in other window.
(advice-add 'yas-new-snippet :override 'my/yas-new-snippet )
```

Comment: How about `cl-letf`?  E.g., `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) #'my-y-or-n-p)) ...)`

Comment: @lawlist Isn't that the same thing that I did with `(advice-add 'yas-new-snippet :override 'my/yas-new-snippet )` ? I was wondering if I could override switch-to-buffer inside yas-new-snippet without going inside of the code if that makes sense. Override it from the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding @lawlist's comment above, here's how to do it with `cl-letf`.

Let's start with a simple example: you have a function `foo` which calls a function `bar` with an argument (`foo` is the analog of the `yas-new-snippet` function in your case and `bar` is the analog of `switch-to-buffer`) and I want to change `foo` to call a different function `baz` instead (the analog of `switch-to-buffer-other-window` in your case), but from the "outside". So here are the three functions:

```el
  (defun foo ()
    (bar "foo"))

  (defun bar (x)
    (message (format "%s:%s" "bar" x)))

  (defun baz (x)
    (message (format "%s:%s" "baz" x)))

  (foo) ---> "bar:foo"
```

Define a new function that (effectively) calls `baz` instead of `bar` - that's the analog of your `my/yas-new-snippet` function:

```el
  (defun my/foo ()
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'bar) #'baz))
      (foo)))
```

Now when I call `my-foo`, it calls `baz` instead of `bar`:

```el
(my-foo) ----> "baz:foo"
```

Note that we are not touching `foo` at all. We are just temporarily modifying the function cell of the `bar` symbol to hold the `baz` function instead. We then call `foo` which *thinks* it's calling `bar`, but we have pulled a switcheroo and it's (effectively) calling `baz` instead. And then we are out of scope of `cl-letf` and everything is back the way it was.

So in your case, you can do this:

```el
(defun my/yas-new-snippet (&optional no-template)
  (interactive "P")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'switch-to-buffer) #'switch-to-buffer-other-window))
     (yas-new-snippet no-template)))
```

I haven't actually tested this (I *did* test the toy example above), so I hope this works but I'm reasonably sure that it will.
EDIT: As the OP points out in a comment, in order for the new function to be compatible with the old function, not only does it have to have the same signature, but it also has to have the same interactive specification, so that the optional argument is handled the same way.

Since we are using the old `yas-new-snippet` function inside the new function, you should *not* override the old function with the new one: that would cause an infinite descent. The new function calls the old functions so you need both functions to stick around in Emacs's memory. Instead of the overriding advice, just bind the new function to whatever key the old function was bound to.

Here's a [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/whats-the-correct-replacement-for-flet-on-new-emacsen) with more information and here is [Malabarba's article](http://endlessparentheses.com/understanding-letf-and-how-it-replaces-flet.html) that is linked from one of the answers to that question. I found both of these very illuminating.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, that makes a lot of sense now. You're basically overriding the function bar from the local scope of my/foo which I will bind to my own key. So I will have both functions, the normal one  and the override one from my key binding.

Comment: You will only have one function bound to the key (either the old one or the new one). The point is that the new function uses the old function so they will both have to be around (i.e. in Emacs's memory). If you want to be able to call both quickly, then you will have to bind each to a separate key (but I doubt that is necessary).

Comment: I edited the answer a bit to clarify: it was indeed a bit confusing.

Comment: I understand. Thanks, I added `(interactive "P")` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks! I added that to the answer..